# Working on multi-camera edits using proxy files in Premiere

Tags: premiere, multi-camera, intermediate

I want to be able to make multi-camera edits using low res proxy files, then be able to recreate those edits using HD footage. I'm using CC 2019. Here's my workflow:

1. Import HD files into Premiere, and create a multi-camera source
   sequence
2. Select the clips, right click them and create proxies

When I open the Multi-camera Source Sequence in Timeline, I can toggle the proxy files by clicking the Toggle Proxies button.

When I create a Sequence from my Multi-camera Source Sequence, and open it in the timeline, I am no longer able to Toggle Proxies.

Is this the expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

I have found [this workaround](https://youtu.be/GaNPlbTt0y4), but it involves duplicating the multi-camera sequence, and swapping out the footage for the low-res footage. I'd prefer Premiere to manage toggling the proxies itself if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you globally turn on/off proxies in the preferences does that work?

[image]

Because premiere sometimes drops resolution while playing, it can be hard to see whether a proxy is enabled or not. You can test it by rendering a proxy with a watermark and seeing if it goes away when you turn off proxies.

Comment: No it didn't work for me.